# Is it possible to use normal html (Further Vue/React components) to send data to a Bokeh plot?

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

I've been trying almost everything from Bokeh documentation and I don't know if this is possible.

What I want is to use regular html (input/textbox/table and later a Vue/React component) to get the data to be used by the bokeh server application, however I don't want to embed the bokeh and use http requests, I would like them to run together. Ideally selecting something on the Vue component, would fire a callback to my bokeh server on python, so it would update a plot. So far it seems to me it that this is only doable through Bokeh widgets.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks